# Validate input and repeat input if it was invalid

Tags: c#, winforms

Using Visual Studio, its an exercise, I need to add other students in, which isn't a problem. My main question is: I want the code to jump back to the input question if the value is above 100 or below 0 included, but I don't know the code that checks(validates) the user-input, any help would be very helpful and I would be incredibly grateful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Student_Marks_For_Statement
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char moreData;
            double total = 0;
            double secondTotal = 0;
            for (double student1 = 0; student1 == 0; student1++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter mark for student 1: ");
                student1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                total += student1;



                Console.WriteLine("Any more data? Enter 'y' or 'n' then return");
                moreData = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                if (moreData == 'n')
                {
                    ;
                }
                if (moreData == 'y')
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter Value :");
                    secondTotal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    total += secondTotal;
                }

                for (double student2 = 0; student2 == 0; student2++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter mark for student 2: ");
                    student2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    total += student2;
                    student2++;

                    Console.WriteLine("Any more data? Enter 'y' or 'n' then return");
                    moreData = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (moreData == 'n')
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                    if (moreData == 'y')
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter Value :");
                        secondTotal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        total += secondTotal;
                        student2++;

                    } Console.WriteLine("Total marks = : {0}", total);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you at the very least give your question a descriptive title? That you need help is obvious, but it tells us nothing about the question you're about to ask.

Comment: How about using methods? If you lazy you can use "goto" but thats very very very bad practice.

Comment: Its my first time using this website, so i apologize for the lack of details within the title.

Comment: To which line you want to jump exactly?

Comment: I want it to jump back to the input question, so when the value is checked and its above 100, or below 0, it will go back to the input question and display a message saying invalid, i can use an if statement, but i currently don't know how to check the input to see if its within range.

Comment: Basically requiring the user to try a gain.

Comment: That has to be the most interesting use of a for loop I've seen in ~30 years of writing code....

Comment: You'' have to excuse that, Iv'e followed spys advice and put them in individual methods, I'm only within my 3rd week of the course.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I just followed your code and organized them within methods.

```
public class Program
{
    public static char DecisionSign = ' ';
    public static double TotalMarkOfFirstStudent = 0;
    public static double TotalMarkOfSecondStudent = 0;
    public static double inputValue = 0;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter mark for student 1: ");
        while (DecisionSign != 'n')
        {
            CalculateFirstStudentResult();
        }

        DecisionSign=' ';
        Console.WriteLine("Enter mark for student 2: ");
        while (DecisionSign != 'n')
        {
            CalculateSecondStudentResult();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Student 1 got total : " + TotalMarkOfFirstStudent);
        Console.WriteLine("Student 2 got total : " + TotalMarkOfSecondStudent);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static char CalculateFirstStudentResult()
    {
        DecisionSign = ' ';
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Value : ");
        inputValue = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (inputValue >= 0 && inputValue <= 100)
        {
            TotalMarkOfFirstStudent += inputValue;
            Console.WriteLine("Any more data? Enter 'y' or 'n' then return");
            DecisionSign = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        else
        {
            CalculateFirstStudentResult();
        }
        return DecisionSign;
    }

    public static char CalculateSecondStudentResult()
    {
        DecisionSign = ' ';
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Value : ");
        inputValue = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (inputValue >= 0 && inputValue <= 100)
        {
            TotalMarkOfSecondStudent += inputValue;
            Console.WriteLine("Any more data? Enter 'y' or 'n' then return");
            DecisionSign = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        else 
        {
            CalculateSecondStudentResult();
        }
        return DecisionSign;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just looking over your advised code, looks good to me, thank you, I'll see how this performs.

Comment: Code seems to crash out after pressing a button on student 2, also, just to point out, the "anymore data" question comes after the first input, so the user gets to add more if yes, or leave the value entered and push on to the next student.

Comment: This isn't the best solution.You can divide it into classes and more methods. Just have to keep in mind that it's better to divide your code into possible sections. Make it understandable to human.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked it yet, i had an idea, but it didn't work unfortunately, it has to be in my programming style so it looks legit, basically I'm just trying to figure out, on a very basic, beginners level, within an if statement, if the value entered is below or above the required, it doesn't store the value and it'll re-loop that particular method.

Comment: The following program does the same thing. If the value is >= 0 or <= 100 it adds it to the total else it makes a recursive call to the Method. You should get some fundamental course. That will help you understand basic programming. And if my answer suggest through the correct way it should be marked as answer.

Comment: @codeSpy - "You should get some fundamental course." OP has stated they are only in the third week of the course, and I think they have made it clear that they are at the beginning of learning.  The assignment given is a good intro assignment for learning user input, validating user input and loop structures.  You have to walk before you can run.

Comment: That is correct, my course started September 2nd, but we didn't start coding until after the induction, so September 9th, its part time, 3 hours of procedural programming a week, pass criteria is taught, we home study the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some psuedo-code that will continue to accept user input until they enter "n", and validate that the user input is between 0 and 100 (inclusive):

```
moredata = "y"

while moredata = "y"
   Prompt for score
   Convert score to double

   if score <= 0 or score >= 100
      Tell user score must be betwen 0 and 100
      moredata = "y"
   else
      Add score to total
   end if

   ask user if they have more data

   show total score
 end while
```

The `while` loop will continue to prompt the user for information until they enter "n". If the score is less than 0 or greater than 100 it will tell the user the score is out of bounds and they'll be prompted to input data again.  Otherwise, it will add the score to the total, show the running total and then ask if the user has more data.

I would recommend using `double.TryParse` on the conversion to avoid errors (for example, what if the user enters a string?).

Also, your for loops will only execute one time, which makes them non-useful in this scenario.

Comment: We are learning psuedo-code in a weeks time i think, the for loops where my first attempt, i was just looking to run the loop once to obtain the data, push out the running total, but i was trying to figure out or get help with how to force the user to enter another number if the first input was out-of-range.

Comment: Having read the psuedo-code over a few times, its done exactly what i wanted it to do, thank you Tim.

Comment: @RayneBlackham - You're welcome.  Good luck in your class and happy programming!